# stripe api curl subscription how to add to cart and get status each month

Tags: api, curl, stripe-payments, subscription

The question is about stripe API on how to add it in cart and getting the status of a subscription ID....

I'm following https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/examples

Scenario example:

• Create product, Update price `-d "recurring[interval]"=month -d unit_amount=3569`

• Client pays in cart

• I want to do a cron job to check each month if the subscription ID (production / price IDs) have been successfully charged and processed to update it in my database.

Notes; I integrated a regular normal charge,
I do `<form action="stripe_charge.php" method="post"...`
`<input type="hidden" name="stripe-currency" .... etc`...
but I can't find the documentation for subscription...

--1-- but how to add the plan / subscription in the cart form ?

--2-- How the curl would look like to get the status each month ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your first question I'm not sure what the answer is, as I can't see your entire form or backend code, but I think [Stripe's guide for creating fixed-price Subscriptions using Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price) might help.

Regarding your second question, instead of a cron job that polls every month, you can [set up a webhook endpoint that will receive Subscription-related events from Stripe as they happen](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks).

If you want to avoid webhooks and poll instead (not recommended as it will use more resources and be less timely) you can [list Events using the API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list?lang=python).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, I love best the last portion of your answer. `curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/events` will be good in my case ;)

Comment: Very happy to help!